# Default output_format for all templates if not specified in Freemarker 2.3.28

Tags: spring, freemarker

I am using Freemarker version 2.3.28. I don't specify my output format (`output_format`) anywhere in my templates or in configuration. Does that mean output format for all templates is set to `HTML` by default? If that's the case I believe `${value}` will be always escaped?

Answer (score 1):

By default the `output_format` of templates is `undefined` so, no auto-escaping will happen. It's like that for backward compatibility. To enable HTML auto-escaping, do one of these:

- Set the `incompatible_improvements` configuration setting to at least 2.3.24 (but generally the higher the better), and the use `ftlh` file extension for your template files, instead of the traditional `ftl`. Then the `ftlh` files will have HTML auto-escaping.
- If you keep using `ftl` file extension, you can just set the `output_format` configuration setting to HTML. So then that will be the default for all templates. If only some templates need auto-escaping, you can use the `template_configurations` setting to map different output formats depending on template path patterns.

See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_outputformatsautoesc.html